# Order by number of views in last hour [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table which holds all views for the last 24 hours. I want to pull all pages ordered by a rank. The rank should be calculated something like this:

```
rank = (0.3 * viewsInCurrentHour) * (0.7 * viewsInPreviousHour)
```

I want the prefferably in one single query. Is this possible, or do I need to make 2 queries (one for the current hour and one for the last hour and then just aggregate them)?

Here is the `DESCRIBE` of the table `accesslog`:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| aid       | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sid       | varchar(128)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| title     | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| path      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url       | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hostname  | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uid       | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| timer     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| timestamp | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What are the (relevant) columns in your table, and what is your table name?

Comment: Have you tried this in two queries? Please post your initial queries.

Comment: What @Bohemian said. Even better, just paste in your `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: You might have meant - `rank = (0.3 * viewsInCurrentHour) PLUS (0.7 * viewsInPreviousHour)`

Comment: @SabbirYousufSanny I know that your formula would make more sense normally, but for what we're doing, my formula gives better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    url,
    sum(timestamp between subdate(now(), interval 2 hour) and subdate(now(), interval 1 hour)) * .3 +
    sum(timestamp between subdate(now(), interval 1 hour) and now()) * .7 as rank
from whatever_your_table_name_is_which_you_have_kept_secret
where timestamp > subdate(now(), interval 2 hour)
group by url
order by rank desc;
```

The `sum(condition)` works because in mysql `trye` is `1` and `false` is `0`, so summing a condition is the same as what some noobs write as `sum(case when condition then 1 else 0 end)`

#### Edit:

Note the addition of `where timestamp > subdate(now(), interval 2 hour)` to improve performance, because only these records contribute to the result.

Comment: works. with the specification that i needed to convert `from_unixtime(timestamp)` because i was keeping the timestamp, but that's my fault for not specifying. it takes 0.7 seconds on a 30k records table. ouch! thanks.

Comment: you're absolutely right. it's down to 0.1 seconds. thank you :)